# Example of a nonlinear compact operator that is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, nonlinear-analysis

We know from functional analysis that if a linear map is compact, then it is continuous. Now I want to find a nonlinear compact map that is not continous. Can someone help me with an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $F(x) = \arctan(x)$ for $x<0$ and $F(x) = \arctan(x)+1$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Are we taking compact to mean that the image of a bounded set has compact closure? (I guess this is as much a question for OP).

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I've read that $F : X\to Y$ is called compact if $\overline{F(X)}$ is compact: https://www.math.uni-augsburg.de/prof/geo/Books-and-Scripts/nonlin_10_.pdf (page 73).

Comment: But then a compact, linear map is no longer compact, or rather, according to this definition, for $V$ and $W$ Banach spaces, we now call $T:V\to W$ compact if $T|_{B(0,1)}$ is compact.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Right. That is also a footnote in the link I refered to.